# Unable to start Kestrel in Docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have an application written against .NETCore 2.0. I can run the application on my CentOS 7 box in a bash without any problems.

I successfully generated a dockerfile and built a docker image.

When I start the image as container with `docker run` I get the following exception:

```
2018-05-09 08:18:02.038 +00:00 [FTL] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel] [ThreadId 4] Unable to start Kestrel.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -99 EADDRNOTAVAIL address not available
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.LibuvFunctions.ThrowError(Int32 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.Bind(IPEndPoint endPoint)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Listener.ListenTcp(Boolean useFileHandle)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Listener.<>c.<StartAsync>b__8_0(Listener listener)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.LibuvThread.DoPostWork()
```

Don't know what **Address not available** means! This address is not in use in my subnet nor is the configured port.  In C# I use the following code to configure Kestrel:

In my Main()

```
var wHost = BuildWebHost(args[1]);
wHost.Run();
```

The `BuildWebHost()` method is defined as:

```
    private static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string hostAddress)
    {
        return new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseSerilog()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            })
            .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
            {
                options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls($"http://{hostAddress}:{ServerPort}")
            .Build();
    }
```

The IP address is passed as argument and `ServerPort` is a constant. In the Docker file I have

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "OperationsManagerServer.dll", "/logs", "172.16.63.250"]
```

Before starting Kestrel the service does a lot of initialization such as loading configruations from a Redis database and initializing things on a MongoDB server. These servers are running on different machines in the same subnet and this just works fine. So I guess networking in my container works.

Any idea what is wrong with Kestrel when it runs inside a container??

Comment: Why not  binding it on all addresses? It's running within the container anyways and you expose the ports to the outside, if it requires to be reachable from outside

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that works and I understand the error message now! Need to use docker compose and setup correct networking, the assigned IP address is in a different subnet and of course, then the provided IP is not available!

Comment: where your run in your ENTRYPOINT?

Answer (score 0):

My warning after execute was `dotnet run ...` or `dotnet app.dll` was

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: (Error -99 EADDRNOTAVAIL address not available)
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app/publish
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
```

But from the host I was unable to access : http://localhost:5000

After several attempts like:

- https://forums.docker.com/t/run-net-core-application-inside-a-docker/72498

This worked for me:

I added this to my Dockerfile in **netcore 1** before the run

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
WORKDIR /app/publish
CMD ["dotnet", "BeautifulRestApi.dll"]
```